# Import Address Table (IAT) Hook Into Windows getaddrinfo Function in Ws2_32.dll

Tags: c++, c, hook, winsock

I am trying to create a hook to grab the URL the user inputs so as to create a blocking filter. I read the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo) and it shows the function as

```
INT WSAAPI getaddrinfo(PCSTR pNodeName, PCSTR pServiceName, const ADDRINFOA *pHints, PADDRINFOA *ppResult);
```

Do I create a pointer to that function as below?

```
// pointer to original getaddrinfo()
int (WINAPI * p_getaddrinfo)(PCSTR pNodeName, PCSTR pServiceName, const ADDRINFOA *pHints, PADDRINFOA *ppResult);
```

Or, should it be something like:

```
int (WSAAPI * p_getaddrinfo)(PCSTR pNodeName, PCSTR pServiceName, const ADDRINFOA *pHints, PADDRINFOA *ppResult);
```

Any help and pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `WINAPI` and `WSAAPI` are just preprocessor macros that resolve to a calling convention, in this case they are both `__stdcall`. But you should use whichever one is mentioned in the documentation. BTW, `getaddrinfo()` is not used with URLs, nor is it the only function that can resolve a hostname to an IP.

Comment: Thank you Remy... I guess what has thrown me off is that the MSDN documentation shows MessageBox definition, for example, 
```
int MessageBox(....
```
And then for getaddrinfo
```
INT WSAAPI getaddrinfo(...
```

For the target process, chrome.exe, getaddrinfo() is what is used if you type a URL into the address bar as confirmed in API Monitor.
So, based on your comment, I should be using something like:
```
int (WSAAPI * getaddrinfo(....
```

Thank you for the guidance. Much appreciated.

Comment: I may be using the term URL wrong... I mean hostname... what gets stored in pNodeName variable in the definition.